# Complete data is not passing into script tag in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller

I'm using angularjs to get data from facebook
  I have written following code.
At the backend,it is giving proper output but for $scope.chart variable but at the front end when I log the data it is showing date:null.I'm uploading images for resprctive data.[Backend Data Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVhgq.png)[frontend data showing date Null](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9LOA8.png)

```
<script>
 function mychart(){
var dom_el = document.querySelector('[ng-controller="myCtrl"]');
        var ng_el = angular.element(dom_el);
        var ng_el_scope = ng_el.scope();
        var data = ng_el_scope.chart;
        //var data = chart;
        console.log(data);

// Set the dimensions of the canvas / graph
var margin = {top: 30, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 270 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// Parse the date / time
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%d-%b-%y").parse;

// Set the ranges
var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

// Define the axes
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
    .orient("bottom").ticks(5);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y)
    .orient("left").ticks(5);

// Define the line
var valueline = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.close); });

// Adds the svg canvas
var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


// Get the data
    data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.date = parseDate(d.date);
        d.close = +d.close;
    });

    // Scale the range of the data
    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
    y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.close; })]);

    // Add the valueline path.
    svg.append("path")  
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("d", valueline(data));

    // Add the X Axis
    svg.append("g")     
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis);

    // Add the Y Axis
    svg.append("g")     
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(yAxis);
 }
</script>
```